Debugging Windows NFS mount
I have a Linux host with an NFS share:
# /etc/exports

/srv/data machineA.the-domain.net(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1001,anonguid=1001)

/srv/data *.the-domain.net(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1002,anonguid=1002)

I mount it on the specific Windows machine machineA via the usual mount -o anon \\nfs-host-machine\srv\data Z:.
Now, sometimes it works as intended, and I have the rights of UID 1001. But sometimes, randomly it seems, it looks like the wildcard export is being used because I have the rights of UID 1002 instead.
How can I debug this?
I have tried:

Checking if the NFS host has the correct IP for the hostname (by pinging, also clearing the DNS cache)
Rerunning exportfs -ar
Remounting the share on Windows

All of these don't work reliably or not at all.
Edit:
After running sudo rpcdebug -m nfsd -s all, here is a part of the syslog where the access fails:
Jul 15 16:12:36 nfs-host kernel: [5727490.777628] nfsd: GETATTR(3)  28: 00070001 01440002 00000000 48446c63 c7433104 b3983c9d
Jul 15 16:12:36 nfs-host kernel: [5727490.777634] nfsd: fh_verify(28: 00070001 01440002 00000000 48446c63 c7433104 b3983c9d)
Jul 15 16:12:37 nfs-host kernel: [5727491.858941] nfsd: GETATTR(3)  36: 01070001 01440002 00000000 48446c63 c7433104 b3983c9d
Jul 15 16:12:37 nfs-host kernel: [5727491.858946] nfsd: fh_verify(36: 01070001 01440002 00000000 48446c63 c7433104 b3983c9d)
Jul 15 16:12:37 nfs-host kernel: [5727491.859341] nfsd: GETATTR(3)  36: 01070001 01440002 00000000 48446c63 c7433104 b3983c9d
Jul 15 16:12:37 nfs-host kernel: [5727491.859344] nfsd: fh_verify(36: 01070001 01440002 00000000 48446c63 c7433104 b3983c9d)
Jul 15 16:12:37 nfs-host kernel: [5727491.979643] nfsd: GETATTR(3)  36: 01070001 01440002 00000000 48446c63 c7433104 b3983c9d
Jul 15 16:12:37 nfs-host kernel: [5727491.979647] nfsd: fh_verify(36: 01070001 01440002 00000000 48446c63 c7433104 b3983c9d)
Jul 15 16:12:38 nfs-host kernel: [5727492.745452] __find_in_sessionid_hashtbl: 1721030894:1958739779:7:0
Jul 15 16:12:38 nfs-host kernel: [5727492.745458] nfsd4_sequence: slotid 0
Jul 15 16:12:38 nfs-host kernel: [5727492.745460] check_slot_seqid enter. seqid 360 slot_seqid 359
Jul 15 16:12:38 nfs-host kernel: [5727492.745464] --> nfsd4_store_cache_entry slot 00000000d138a143
Jul 15 16:12:39 nfs-host kernel: [5727494.569837] __find_in_sessionid_hashtbl: 1721030894:1958739778:6:0
Jul 15 16:12:39 nfs-host kernel: [5727494.569843] nfsd4_sequence: slotid 0
Jul 15 16:12:39 nfs-host kernel: [5727494.569844] check_slot_seqid enter. seqid 17283 slot_seqid 17282
Jul 15 16:12:39 nfs-host kernel: [5727494.569847] --> nfsd4_store_cache_entry slot 00000000af3b3410


Hi, do you have a way to share the logs of the NFS share ?

@Maslie See the edit, are these the correct logs to look at?

Can you try enabling debug logging for rpc.mountd? That's the service which ultimately chooses an exports entry for each client.

The logs you share, seem to be normal logs from NFS share, did the issue happen when you took the logs ? It would be better to have logs when the issue occur.

@Maslie Those are logs from when the access failed (as in, used to wrong rule).

@grawity_u1686 How can I do that? I set debug=1 in the [mountd] section of /etc/nfs.conf, but I don't know where the log will appear.
